# Transform triangles into a list of vertex indices with JTS and DelaunayTriangulationBuilder

Tags: java, gis, jts

I have this little piece of code:

```java
DelaunayTriangulationBuilder builder = new DelaunayTriangulationBuilder();
builder.setSites(geometry);
builder.setTolerance(0.0000001);
Geometry triangulation = builder.getTriangles(new GeometryFactory());
```

It will tessellate a Geometry to create a list of triangles. I want to use this result in a 3d application, but in order to optimize the storage space I would like to have it in the following structure:

- An ordered list of unique vertices (of the outter edges)
- A list of vertex indices (cw or ccw) that represent each of the triangles

I have a hard time finding an efficient way to do that using the JTS DelaunayTriangulationBuilder class.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that rather than a `Geometry` you want to work with a [`QuadEdgeSubdivision`](https://javadocng.mobanisto.com/jts-1.17.1/org/locationtech/jts/triangulate/quadedge/QuadEdgeSubdivision.html). Then you can have code like:

```
    QuadEdgeSubdivision quadEdgeSubdivision = builder.getSubdivision();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Collection<QuadEdge> primaryEdges = quadEdgeSubdivision.getPrimaryEdges(false);

    for (QuadEdge edge : primaryEdges) {
      if (quadEdgeSubdivision.isFrameEdge(edge)){
         // this is an outer edge
      }
        // Edges have vertexes and are part of a triangle
        Vertex[] v = new Vertex[3];
        v[0] = edge.orig();
        v[1] = edge.dest();
        v[2] = edge.oNext().dest();
        // or you can get a LineString 
        LineSegment lineSegment = edges[i].toLineSegment();
        ...
     }
```

You can see this sort of thing in action in the [GeoTools Contour process](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/Contours.java#L163) that I [wrote about](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/2020/12/24/contours.html) a couple of years ago.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately it seems that my edges are never on the frame and `quadEdgeSubdivision.isFrameEdge(edge)` never seems to be true. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: try `quadEdgeSubdivision.getPrimaryEdges(true)`? to include the frame

Comment: Unfortunately the frame seems to be a triangle which encloses my geometry. It means that the frame doesn't include the outter edges of my geometry. Basically what I would need is a way to know if an edge is part of only one face. If it is part of two faces, then it would be an inner edge of the geometry. My final goal is to extrude the geometry vertically and build walls on the outter edges. Do you know if I can do that with quad edges? Many thanks!

Comment: so would any triangle involving the frame be on the outside of your geometry?

Comment: I think I may have been confusing with the "outter edge" term. I am trying to get the edges from the original geometry that are not inside the geometry itself. A drawing would probably be easier to explain. For example, if I had a square made of two triangles: what I want is the four exterior edges of the square, and I don't want the edge in the center of the square because during the 3d extrusion, it will be hidden inside the 3d mesh. Does it make better sense like this? The frame of the `QuadEdgeSubdivison` gives me additional edges that are not part of the original geometry.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/270342. Basically I iterate over all the edges of my initial triangulation. Each edge that appears twice is an inside edge. This way I will only keep the exterior edges of my triangulation.